# Pattern Match(es) are Overlapped - Pattern matching on Operators

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I've come across a situation where I would like to pattern match on operators. However, this throws a `Pattern match(es) are overlapped` error with GHC. I can't figure out why. Is pattern matching on operators not allowed? I assume that since enclosing an operator symbol in parentheses [converts it into an identifier](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-240003.2), this should have worked.

```
test :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> String
test (+) = "plus"
test (-) = "minus"
test _ = "other"
```

There are other ways I can accomplish what I want to do. I'm just curious as to why this doesn't work.

Comment: Your first line matches any function and locally binds it to the infix operator +. The subsequent lines are thus surplus to requirements, hence the warning. Note that function symbols, infix or not, can all be locally rebound by pattern matching in this way. Only capitalized constructors (or :-prefixed infix constructors) and literals match only themselves, and then only in first-order types. Haskell gives (almost) no way to inspect the intensional properties of functions: (seq aside) you can exploit only their extensional properties by applying them. "Is this the + function?" isn't allowed.

Comment: @pigworker, this explains why I was getting the 'this binding overshadows the existing prelude definition' message. thanks for the info.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`(+)` and `(-)` are not constructors of the type `Integer -> Integer -> Integer`:

- They are not constructor names
- `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` is not an algebraic datatype

And so your code is equivalent to using any other variable names to bind the first argument, e.g.

```
test foo = "plus"
test bar = "minus"
test _   = "other"
```

which hopefully makes it clear that all three patterns actually match anything (and the first two bind some names). In other words, there is no way for the first pattern (`foo`, or `(+)` in your example) to  fall through, which is why it overlaps with the remaining two.